# Minimization of the SSE

Tags: statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

I'm reading the demonstration in the Book of Wackerly about the minimization of the $\mathrm{SSE}$ for the least square method but there's is a step I don't understand why an $n$ appears where I highlighted after the differentiation. I'm completely lost. Thanks for your help

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial\mathrm{SSE}}{\partial\hat\beta_0} & =\frac{\partial\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n[y_i-(\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_i)]^2\right\}}{\partial\hat\beta_0}=-\sum_{i=1}^n2[y_i-(\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_i)]\\
> & =-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-\color{red}{n\hat\beta_0}-\hat\beta_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)=0
> \end{align*}
> and
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial\mathrm{SSE}}{\partial\hat\beta_1} & =\frac{\partial\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n[y_i-(\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_i)]^2\right\}}{\partial\hat\beta_1}=-\sum_{i=1}^n2[y_i-(\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_i)]x_i\\
> & =-2\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i-\hat\beta_0\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\hat\beta_1\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)=0.
> \end{align*}

Comment: The author has performed the sum with respect to the constant, so $n$ times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{split}-2\sum (y-(\beta_0+\beta_1 x))&=-2\left(\sum y-\beta_0\sum -\beta_1\sum x\right)\text{ distribute}\\
&=-2\left(\sum y-\left(\underbrace{\beta_0+\beta_0+...+\beta_0}_{n}\right)-\beta_1\sum x\right)\\
&=-2\left(\sum y-n\beta_0-\beta_1\sum x\right)\end{split}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$-\sum_{i=1}^n 2[y_i - (\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} x_i)]$$
$$= -2[(y_1 - (\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} x_1)) + (y_2 - (\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} x_2)) + \ldots + (y_n - (\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1} x_n))]$$

Can you see the reason now?